# Git warning: embeded repo

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab, create-react-app

I am having an issue with git. All i am trying to do is to upload react app in folder.

I am using the following:

npx create-react-app task_4_1

After that, I changed the `src` folder files for my purposes and tried to push to git existing folder.

The warning I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\New folder> git add .
warning: adding embedded git repository: task_4_1
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> task_4_1
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached task_4_1
hint:
```

If i follow git commands after all it creates in git see pic below

[image: pic]

All I want is to have my app in a folder. As more folders are going to come here later as learning steps.

Tried to search for answers here. None of the solutions actually helped. None were same problems.

`updated`

I want it to be this way

[image: in Folders]

so I can have 2-8 different react apps in one repo.

If I do all the commands in root folder it comes like so

[image: without folder]

and when I will continue to add new apps down there it will be a huge mess

And if I delete .git File from root that will mean that all node_modules will be uploaded to git as well, Don't we try to avoid that ?

Comment: Seems like you tried to move or copy your `.git` folder. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Haven’t touched it. I can use plain create-react-app with no changes and will have same result.

Comment: `npx create-react-app task_4_1` setups a new React project and initializes a git repository as well. If you don't want the "git repository" that was setup by CRA, just remove the `.git` folder inside `task_4_1` folder.

Comment: As i have only .gitignore file down there. Wouldn’t that mean tgat i will be uploading node_module files as well as .build folder is i will use npm build???

Comment: @RobertL: *you, personally* may not have created two repositories, but commands that you ran, did. Git is warning you that the files in the "inner" repository are *not* being added to the outer repository. Instead, the outer Git has made what I sometimes call a "half-assed" submodule: a submodule that lacks the information needed to clone it. **This is a bad idea** and that's why Git warns you about it.

Comment: Using `git submodule add` turns the half-assed submodule into a fully-assed submodule. Submodules are still tricky and cause users grief, so **be sure you want one**. If you do want one, you want it to be "fully-assed" like this. (If you don't want one, or aren't sure, you probably should back out the submodule setup, remove the inner `.git`, and avoid submodules.)

Comment: @torek If I delete .git file I upload then hole node_modules folder, which is unnecessary, how can i avoid doing that ?

Comment: You have the option of not storing node_modules at all, if that makes sense. Just don't add it.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally create two git files. Just make the structure as the default create-react-app, then in the root folder execute `git init`.

Comment: Haven’t created any git files at all. Even if i try to push exact create-react-app without any changes i get same problem. 

Do u mean just git init in root folder or all the following commands too? As if i use all commands in a root folder it solves a problem with uploading app. But app is not in a folder then.

Comment: Yes, in the root. How do you mean the app is not in a folder?

Comment: Please see `updated` section in question, I explain there with some img what I mean, Thank You!

Comment: @RobertL Git is tracking files, not folders. If the folder is empty, it will be omitted.